# What's the best way to initialize Quartz?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I'm not really sure what is the best way to initialize Quartz to schedule a cron job.
My environment is Tomcat. I have one job that needs to be triggered every day.

Should I create a separate Servlet to initialize Quartz and schedule my job?

**I'm thinking of creating a Servlet and on the init() schedule my job something like this:**

```
SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();
JobDetail jd=new JobDetail("job1","group1",CronJob.class);
CronTrigger ct=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","group2","0 0/1 * * * ?");
sched.scheduleJob(jd,ct);
sched.start();
```

I'm new to Quartz but I guess I always need to keep a reference to the SchedulerFactory in order for Quartz to be running, therefore having that on a Servlet will be best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Cookbook section on the Quartz site](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/index.html).

There are [two easy built-in methods](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler) for starting a Quartz Scheduler within a servlet environment, using either a `<listener>` or `<servlet>` in the app's web.xml.

Comment: Nice link thanks.  I think I'll use listener and in Quartz properties file I'll specify use of XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin to schedule my jobs.