# Which is the recommended way as a client to get handle to the scheduler?

Tags: java, singleton, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler v1.8.3 and is integrated into Apache Tomcat v6.0.10, and hence scheduler is [initialized from within servlet container](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler.html). Jobs are also added/scheduled to scheduler from within Apache Tomcat.

I'm designing a JSP web front end page (quartzAdmin.jsp) from where I only want to see scheduler information like [meta-data](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#getMetaData()) values, all job details along with its triggers, currently executing jobs, etc.

My question is, in order to get a handle to the scheduler, which one of the below 2 option is recommended:

**Option 1: Getting handle by directly calling schedulerFactory.getScheduler()**

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
```

**Option 2: Getting handle by implementing singleton pattern**

```
public class Quartz {

    private Quartz() {
    }

    private static Scheduler scheduler = null;

    public static Scheduler getScheduler() {
        if(scheduler == null) {
            SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
        }
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Then in my quartzAdmin.jsp, just a call *Quartz.getScheduler()* would return a handle to the scheduler.

Comment: A related question on initializing quartz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257074/whats-the-best-way-to-initalize-quartz

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing here is a singleton pattern, and your singleton initialization is not thread-safe.

I would recommend not using singleton here, but instead add a reference to `Quartz` to `ServletContext`, possibly initializing it in `ServletContextListener`.

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>my.package.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**MyServletContextListener.java**

```
package my.package;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public final void contextInitialized (
            final ServletContextEvent event
        )
    {
        final ServletContext servlet_ctx = event.getServletContext( );

        Quartz quartz = new Quartz( );

        servlet_ctx.addAttribute( Quartz.ATTRIBUTE_NAME, quartz );
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed (
            final ServletContextEvent event
        )
    {
        final ServletContext servlet_ctx = event.getServletContext( );

        Quartz.fromContext( servlet_ctx ).shutdown( );

        servlet_ctx.removeAttribute( Quartz.ATTRIBUTE_NAME );
    }
}
```

**Quartz.java**

```
public final static String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = Quartz.class.getName( );

public Quartz( )
{
    ...
}

public static Quartz fromContext( final ServletContext ctx )
{
  return ctx.getAttribute( ATTRIBUTE_NAME );
}

public void shutdown( )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Assuming I don't manipulate anything with scheduler apart from just getting scheduler related information, is it still should be made thread-safe?  Hope you meant "not thread-safe" in this context, am I right?  Also, I'm not able to clearly understand your recommendation mentioned.  Can you explain with some simple code sample?

Comment: @Gnanam. If you intend to call your original getScheduler( ) method directly from JSP ( not recommended ) it will most definitely be called from multiple threads.  Check this post for correct way to initialize singleton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635396/pattern-for-lazy-thread-safe-singleton-instantiation-in-java/3635619#3635619

Answer (score 0):

I think what both options do is create a *new* Scheduler, not getting the one you have configured in `web.xml`.

Currently I am doing this (similar to Option 1):

```
...configure a QuartzInitializerListener for my webapp...
// my servlet's init()
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    ...
    SchedulerFactory factory =
            (SchedulerFactory) config.getServletContext().getAttribute(
                QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY
            );
    Scheduler factory.getScheduler();
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I'm getting a handle to the scheduler which was initialized before from `web.xml`. I can verify this using `scheduler.getMetaData().getSummary()` and check for this line `Running since: xxxxx`

Comment: I believe that this is already taken care by Quartz scheduler itself.

Comment: Well, then there is no need to use a singleton as Quartz is taking care of that. Just use option 1.